# LANG error knitting document in R Studio preview 0.98.864

Tags: r, environment-variables, knitr, rstudio, pandoc

I have a preview release of the R Studio server (0.98.864 Ubuntu version) set up as an EC2 microinstance on AWS.  When I attempt to knit a simple .Rmd document, I get the following error message:

```
Error in with_pandoc_safe_environment({ : 
  The 'LANG' environment variable must be set before running Pandoc.
Calls: <Anonymous> ... FUN -> get_pandoc_version -> with_pandoc_safe_environment
Execution halted
```

I have set the language variables by editing the `/etc/environment`, and for good measure I installed `language-pack-en-base`.  Now when I run `locale` I get:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

So it would seem that the LANG environment variable has been set.

Indeed, when I run R from the command line, I get:

```
> Sys.getenv("LANG",unset=NA)
[1] "en_US.UTF-8"
```

It also appears to have been set for all users, because when I log in as a different user using

```
su - <username>
```

and run `locale`, I get the above results.

However, when I restart the server:

```
sudo rstudio-server restart
```

and then log in to the Server as a user, I get:

```
> is.na(Sys.getenv("LANG", unset = NA))
[1] TRUE
```

My language settings apply to all users, but somehow this information is not getting to the Server.

A partial workaround is to log on to the server as a user and to add

```
Sys.setenv(LANG="en_US.UTF-8")
```

to my `.Rprofile`.  However, this applies to only one user at a time, and I would like to fix the problem for all users at once.

Can someone see where I have gone wrong?

Or is there another configuration file in R that must be modified?  I have tried creating and adding various commands to `/etc/rstudio/rserver.conf` and to `/etc/rstudio/rsession.conf` (see [this document](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/server/configuration)), but nothing survives the configuration test.

Comment: I do not think it is likely that you ever need to edit /etc/environment. Anyway, my `LANGUAGE` and `LC_ALL` are empty (both Debian and Ubuntu) by default. That might be the reason. What does `locale` return if you do not edit /etc/environment?

Comment: @Yihui, looks like it is also true for me (Ubuntu 14.04) that LC_ALL and LANGUAGE are empty by default.  After commenting the language edits out of `/etc/environment` and logging back on, `locale` tells me that LANGUAGE and LC_ALL are empty.  (LANG is en_US.UTF-8.)

Comment: I just tested the latest preview version of RStudio Server on Debian, and I did not see the problem. Since `locale` gave you the correct LANG variable, I have no idea how RStudio Server could not recognize it.

Comment: @Yihui, I'm puzzled, too, but for now it's fine for me to write a line of `bash` code to add the needed the `Sys.setenv()` command to the .Rprofile of all my current users (all of whom want LANG to be en).  If I run across anything else I'll let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LANG` variable will be set to `en_US.UTF-8` in **rmarkdown** if not already set. This change was brought in the commit [bb2d87f](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/commit/bb2d87f8b8cc18234039130ceecfc8180dc90ea4).

Comment: that should do it!  Thanks!